# What should I read when returning to C++ (from Java)?

Tags: java, c++, programming-languages, transition

I am working with Java at my current day job. When I learned programming, I learned C++, but haven't touched it (or had to) since 2002. I don't even remember how to do the simplest of things.

Lately, my work has been expressing a need for a C++ application built for windows.

I am looking for books/articles/blog-posts (resources) that:

- teach the basics of C++?

  - for n00bz?
  - for someone who's already been programming?
- teach the differences between C++ and Java?
- teach the basics of the Visual .* platform?
- teach the specificities of building with Visual Studio?

**Why ask the question?**

This question was brought on by the fact that my first program is 5 lines of C++ (sourced from documentation with a dependency on a DLL.) It's quite intimidating to figure out how to build it in the way I'd like to.

That being said, there are many elements in the snippet that I don't understand.

I definitely see that the original need is small, but I'd like to get some background on the platform/subject before I embark on even some simpler development (like the snippet) in the future.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the exact same background, and switching to C++ from Java (or anything else) is always a pain.  I try to use alternative native languages like C, Objective-C, and C# whenever possible.  When C++ is unavoidable, I find I get the best results by treating C++ as "C with classes (single-inheritance, no friends)", as then I don't have to worry about the large number of unique, quirky, and nonessential features that exist in C++.

Comment: Some of my favorite sources:
C++ Primer plus is a great book to refresh your memory on the nuances of c++.

My favorite style Guide.
http://geosoft.no/development/cppstyle.html.

A good best practices book is Effective C++.
http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Specific-Addison-Wesley-Professional-Computing/dp/0201924889.


I am glad to see that you are not just jumping into c++ without brushing up. I read and code c++ all day, and i must say, it is easy to write c++, but its really difficult to write GOOD c++ code.

Comment: this thread shouldn't have been closed.

Comment: @Scoobie. Don't listen to aroth. If you're going back to C++, be a professional, and do it the right way, not the lazy way. **RAII is the most important thing in C++. Everything else is related.** Learn all its paradigm and don't even limit yourself to only one (C-style, or single-inheritance-OOP-style, etc.). In particular, once you understand their power, templates will blow your mind open, and you'll never look at java's generics the same way. In fact, once you'll understand C++ true power, you'll never look at other C-like languages the same way. **And don't forget RAII.**

Comment: @paercebal -- Thanks. I will have to find a SO question about C++ books.